# Is it possible and if so how do install wordpress as a secondary site on 1 domain

Tags: wordpress

Basically I have a website that I built in html and don't want to touch but what I would like to do if its possible is install Wordpress in a sub directory on the same site sort of like a holding area to showcase a wordpress site I am working on! I tried simply adding a new directory to the domain and copying over the wordpress folder but this didnt work so im just wondering if anyone knows how to do what im looking for can they help me out please!

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: The original website is not a wordpress site, its just a normal HTML website its not a blog or anything, I already have other HTML websites in subdirectories im just looking to have one subdirectory that uses wordpress.

For example:

main site = www.mywebsite.com (Built in html)

1st subsite = www.mywebsite.com/siteb (built in html)

2nd subsite = www.mywebsite.com/sitec (using wordpress)

Comment: If you are a developer/designer, it would be worth getting a hosting account where you can create as many subdomains as you need. If you don't mind doing a bit of trivial Linux admin, I recommend getting a VPS - they are extremely cheap these days, and it adds a great deal of flexibility to your hosting requirements. FWIW, I'd always run WP from a domain root, and certainly not one installation inside another - I'd expect the `.htaccess` rules to conflict.

Comment: You *could* run them from different subdirectories as long as the parent site wasn't WordPress, but I agree using subdomains is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress can be install in a subdirectory - by default the download will unzip into a folder called `wordpress` which you can rename if you would like. If you run the install from the subdirectory it should set the proper `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` values, but if not or if you currently have WordPress installed in the root and want to move it to a subdirectory, you can follow this guide to [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory).

Comment: But the original website is not a wordpress site, its just a normal HTML website its not a blog or anything, i already have other HTML websites in subdirectories im just looking to have one subdirectory that uses wordpress. 

For example:

main site = www.mywebsite.com (Built in html)
1st subsite = www.mywebsite.com/siteb (built in html)
2nd subsite = www.mywebsite.com/sitec (using wordpress)

Comment: In that case, yes, you can definitely install WordPress in a subdirectory. See my edits.